# Python image file manipulation

Tags: python, dictionary

Python beginner here. I am trying to make us of some data stored in a dictionary. 
I have some .npy files in a folder. It is my intention to build a dictionary that encapsulates the following: reading of the map, done with np.load, the year, month, and date of the current map (as integers), the fractional time in years (given that a month has 30 days - it does not affect my calculations afterwards), and the number of pixels, and number of pixels above a certain value. At the end I expect to get a dictionary like:

```
{'map0':'array(from np.load)', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'fractional_time', 'pixels'
 'map1':'....}
```

What I managed until now is the following:

```
import glob
file_list = glob.glob('*.npy')

def only_numbers(seq):  #for getting rid of any '.npy' or any other string
    seq_type= type(seq)
    return seq_type().join(filter(seq_type.isdigit, seq))

maps = {}
for i in range(0, len(file_list)-1):
    maps[i] = np.load(file_list[i])
    numbers[i]=list(only_numbers(file_list[i]))
```

I have no idea how to to get a dictionary to have more values that are under the for loop. I can only manage to generate a new dictionary, or a list (e.g. numbers) for every task. For the numbers dictionary, I have no idea how to manipulate the date in the format YYYYMMDD to get the integers I am looking for.

For the pixels, I managed to get it for a single map, using:

```
data = np.load('20100620.npy')
print('Total pixel count: ', data.size)
c = (data > 50).astype(int)
print('Pixel >50%: ',np.count_nonzero(c))
```

Any hints? Until now, image processing seems to be quite a challenge.

Edit: Managed to split the dates and make them integers using

```
date=list(only_numbers.values())
year=int(date[i][0:4])
month=int(date[i][4:6])
day=int(date[i][6:8])
print (year, month, day)
```

Comment: Would be best, if you could use the title to summarize what is your question

Comment: Maybe you need not dictionary but class: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm

Comment: @StanislavIvanov Thanks for the tip. OOP is a bit too hard to grasp at the moment. I posted something I managed to do that does the job, although it's not the best :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, I managed to do something else. I dropped the idea of a dictionary containing everything, as I needed to manipulate further easier. I did the following:

```
file_list = glob.glob('data/...')  # files named YYYYMMDD.npy
file_list.sort()

def only_numbers(seq): # i make sure that i remove all characters and symbols from the name of the file
    seq_type = type(seq)
    return seq_type().join(filter(seq_type.isdigit, seq))

numbers = {}
time = []
np_above_value = []

for i in range(0, len(file_list) - 1):
    maps = np.load(file_list[i])
    maps[np.isnan(maps)] = 0   # had some NANs and getting some errors
    numbers[i] = only_numbers(file_list[i]) # getting a dictionary with the name of the files that contain only the dates - calling the function I defined earlier
    date = list(numbers.values()) # registering the name of the files (only the numbers) as a list
    year = int(date[i][0:4]) # selecting first 4 values (YYYY) and transform them as integers, as required
    month = int(date[i][4:6]) # selecting next 2 values (MM)
    day = int(date[i][6:8]) # selecting next 2 values (DD)
    time.append(year + ((month - 1) * 30 + day) / 360) # fractional time

    print('Total pixel count for map '+ str(i) +':', maps.size) # total number of pixels for the current map in iteration
    c = (maps > value).astype(int)
    np_above_value.append (np.count_nonzero(c)) # list of the pixels with a value bigger than value
    print('Pixels with concentration >value% for map '+ str(i) +':', np.count_nonzero(c)) # total number of pixels with a value bigger than value for the current map in iteration

plt.plot(time, np_above_value)  # pixels with concentration above value as a function of time
```

I know it might be very clumsy. Second week of python, so please overlook that. It does the trick :)